# A method to Skip both start and end character index in Java substring?

Tags: java

I'm trying to see if there is a method by which I can skip **both** the start and end indices in a substring function,since substring is traditionally inclusive of the start and exclusive of the end index.
For example,

```
String str="Hello 42 World!";
int hello=str.indexOf("Hello");
int world=str.indexOf("World!");
int fortytwo=customSubstringMethod(str,hello,world);//should be 42.
```

Any insight on how this can be done will be appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A quick and dirty solution without checking error conditions:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str="Hello 42 World!";
    System.out.println(customSubstringMethod(str, "Hello", "World!"));
}

private static String customSubstringMethod(String str, String start, String stop) {
    return str.substring(str.indexOf(start) + start.length(), str.indexOf(stop));
}
```

Besides, you need to know more then the index of the prefix string. The length is required as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
private static String subStringMethod(String value,String start, String end)
{
    return value.substring(value.indexOf(start)+start.length(), value.indexOf(end)).trim();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

There is no such method in the Java API, but you could create a wrapper to do that:

```
public static String customSubstring(String str, int start, int end) {
    return str.substring(start+1,end);
}
```

By the way, be careful with indexOf, it always returns the index of the first character of the occurrence:

```
String str="Hello 42 World!";
int hello=str.indexOf("Hello"); //returns 0
int world=str.indexOf("World!"); // returns 9
int fortytwo=customSubstring(str,hello,world);//returns "ello 42 "
```

So for the first index you should use:

```
String h="Hello";
int hello=str.indexOf(h)+h.length;
```

Comment: @Harmlezz The OP is just asking for a method to exclude both indexes while indexOf includes the starting one.

Comment: I mentioned very clearly in the example that it should return "42" and not "ello 42". Clearly this doesnt solve the problem.

Comment: I pointed that you were misusing the indexOf method and I added the correct use (taking into account the length of the substring. Read the whole answer